# GtkMenuButton popups

Tags: gnome, gtk3, pygobject

after adding menu to GtkMenuButton it is not showing,tried different box to contain it(no use),anyone can say what i amdoing wrong?

```
    from gi.repository import Gtk


    class Window(Gtk.Window):
        def __init__(self):
            Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
            self.set_default_size(400, 200)
            self.set_default_geometry(400, 200)

            hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
            hb.props.show_close_button = True
            hb.props.title = "Click me"
            self.set_titlebar(hb)

            box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
            pmenu = Gtk.Menu()
            pmenu.append(Gtk.MenuItem(label="lp"))
            pmenu.append(Gtk.MenuItem(label="pl"))
            mb = Gtk.MenuButton(popup=pmenu)
            box.add(mb)
            hb.pack_end(box)

    win = Window()
    win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
    win.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

By experience it seems that you're not making them visible:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.set_default_size(400, 200)
        self.set_default_geometry(400, 200)

        hb = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        hb.props.show_close_button = True
        hb.props.title = "Click me"
        self.set_titlebar(hb)

        box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        pmenu = Gtk.Menu()
        for ml in ['lp', 'pl']:
            mi = Gtk.MenuItem(label=ml)
            mi.show()
            pmenu.append(mi)
        mb = Gtk.MenuButton(popup=pmenu)
        box.add(mb)
        hb.pack_end(box)

win = Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Don't know why win.show_all doesn't show them too. Again, I say, I deduced that by experience.

See also:

[Programatically add new menu items to menu item PyGObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582745/programatically-add-new-menu-items-to-menu-item-pygobject/21613240#21613240)